# python for loop output as list

Tags: python, django, for-loop, output

I need to get some calculations for a range of elements at an array.

So, at my views.py my code is:

```
(...)
for f in enumerate(array)
    calc1 = value_x
    calc2 = value y
(...)
```

and, when I print calc1, for example, my output returns

```
1
1
1
1
1
0.98
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

and,  my output has to be like this

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0.98', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

I've already tried to do something like

```
testLi = []
for f in enumerate(array):
    testLi.append(str(TPR_class))
print 'testLI {}'.format(testLi)
```

but it gives me

```
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98', '0.98']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
testLI ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Somebody could help me, please?

Thank you.

Comment: what's TPR_class?

Comment: and what is your array? is it a list, dict?

Comment: TPR_class is the name of my variable

Comment: and my array a list of subcategories that i'm diving my csv column so that i can make filters to and obtain my calculations. I don't know if I'm being explicit

Comment: I load a csv and filter the data as a result of a particular column. Then for each of these filters I have to count the different corresponding records and do some additional calculations. Since the array has always invariant size, I did the calculations through a for loop so that I could get the results dynamically

Comment: I meant what was the actual type of python data structure those were. Efficiency of solutions differ based on the data structures used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need your values output as a list, I would recommend using a list comprehension rather than a for loop, if possible. It is faster and easier to read, and it should produce the results you want. For example, if the values you need printed are stored in *array*, I would use the following code:

[str(x) for x in array]

By using hard brackets around your code, each value is compiled into a list following evaluation as a string value.

Hope this proves helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns tuples that contain indexes into the array along with their values (0,'item1') (1,'item2') etc. But given your interest in 'x', I'm going to assume that your input is actually a dictionary and you are interested in a list of keys ('key1','item1') ('key2','item2') etc.

If you're in Python3, use [items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict.items) on the dictionary to get an iterator over the sequence. And use a looping shortcut for key,value to immediately extract the key and a value for each item as the loop progresses.

Then using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you can build the final list in one line:

```
mydict = {'a':'b','c':'d','f':'g'}
print([str(x) for x,y in mydict.items()])
```

If you don't need the value parts and just the keys, you can simplify to

```
print([str(key) for key in mydict])
```